# Save user input dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pickle

Im trying to find a suitable method to save a dictionary that has user input data and also data that comes from my program (battleship game). The user input data is player name and the rest is the state of the game (like current game, scores, ...).

I did some searching and tried to use Pickle to save this data. 
My dictionary is stored here:

```
def game():
    return {
        'players': [],
        'active_players':[],
        'running_game': False,
```

Im getting the player data from here:

```
def player_register(mm,name):
    board1_for_ship_placement = create_grid(columns_size,rows_size)
    board2_for_showing = create_grid(columns_size,rows_size)
    player = {
        'name':name,
        'played_games': 0,
        'victory': 0,
        'ships_available' : {
            "lancha":0,
            "submarino":0,
            "fragata":0,
            "cruzador":0,
            "porta_avioes":0
        },
        'ships_in_use':[],
        'board1': board1_for_ship_placement,
        'board2': board2_for_showing
    }

    mm['players'].append(player)
```

THIS is the data I need to save and be able to load again on my program. **Name**, **played games** and **victorys**.

This method gathers info from dictionaries.

Now I have seen some examples like this:

```
import pickle
my_dict = {“example”:”dog”, “example2″:”cat”}
with open(‘myfile.txt’, ‘wb’) as f:
pickle.dump(mydict, f)
```

Load:

```
f = open(‘myfile.txt’, ‘rb’)
new_dict = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Now, how can I modify this to save my data?
I have tried this but with no results:

```
import pickle
**my_dict = game()**
with open(‘myfile.txt’, ‘wb’) as f:
pickle.dump(mydict, f)
```

Anyone can help me? I doesn't need to by pickle, JSON is also fine.

Comment: You could just save the data to a json file.

Comment: @BaileyKocin exactly, but how can I do it?

Comment: Well like everything in python you "import name" search name on Google. Then use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this. OP needs a guide/tutorial, or the documentation, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I read the documentation and it doesn't mention this. Only simple dictionary.

Comment: @lordvader _Only simple dictionary_ Is your data not a dictionary? You wrote about pickle and JSON in your post, but didn't go into detail about the most important aspect here, the data.

Comment: The `my_dict = game()` should have worked. What do you mean there were "no results"? Please provide a [mre] so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. From your example I'd say - before calling `game` you would load the dictionary; then `game` would modify or add to that dictionary and return it; then you would dump the dictionary to the same filename.

Comment: @AMC Im using my game() method because It gathers different dictionaries and I need to save them all.

Comment: @lordvader I think you mentioned the wrong person. Please provide **all** the necessary code and data, as well as a detailed and fleshed out explanation of your program.

Comment: Actually we don't need _all_ your code, it would be preferable to have just enough (i.e the minimum) that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AMC I think I added useful information now. I added my register method that has the info I need to gather.

Comment: @lordvader It looks like you should be able to use the json module without any problem. Case closed?

Answer (score 0):

I added some sample data to the `game` function and it worked fine. If you don't get the right result, maybe something is wrong with your `game` function.

Save:

```
import pickle


def game():
    return {
        'players': ['p1', 'p2'],
        'active_players': ['a_p1', 'a_p2'],
        'running_game': False
    }


my_dict = game()
with open("my_data.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(my_dict, f)
```

Load:

```
import pickle

with open("my_data.pkl", "rb") as f:
    my_data = pickle.load(f)

print(my_data)
# Output:
# {'players': ['p1', 'p2'], 'active_players': ['a_p1', 'a_p2'], 'running_game': False}
```

Comment: Would this work with an empy dictionary? Because only after the program launches, user inputs name, before that is empty.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it and give you some feedback.

Comment: @lordvader Yes, If the dictionary is empty, you'll get {'players': [], 'active_players': [], 'running_game': False}

Comment: How could I load this to my main(), because I need to input in my menu the letter S (for Saving) and it should output something like "Game Saved". I added your save code inside a method (def saving():"code")

Comment: @lordvader It isn't entirely clear what you're asking, can you be more specific?

Comment: @AMC I have a function in my main() that works as a menu. Everytime the user presses a letter it will do a different function. My question is, how can I use this method by user input? Something like user press "S" to save game. And it would output "Game Saved"!

Comment: @lordvader That’s a different question entirely, then. You can probably find an answer to that here on SO, and if not I know there are plenty of relevant resources online.